# Default self-signed certificate is used instead of custom certificate in apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, hostname

I've configured three sites (SITE1, SITE2, SITE3) on my server and secured all of them with the help of let's encrypt. Two of them works fine. But one of them (SITE1) shows "This Connection is Untrusted" error when connecting via HTTPS (self-signed cert).

Probably, the issue is that hostname of the server is equal to SITE1 and I can't change it (this is a virtual container). And for this reason the default configuration (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`) is used for SITE1 instead of custom one (`/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE1-le-ssl.conf`).

How can I force apache to use custom configuration for SITE1 instead of the default?

Output of httpd -S:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server SITE1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost SITE1 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost SITE2 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE2-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.SITE2
         port 443 namevhost SITE3 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE3-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.SITE3
         port 443 namevhost SITE1 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE1-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.SITE1

*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server SITE2 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE2.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost SITE2 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE2.conf:1)
                 alias www.SITE2
         port 80 namevhost SITE3 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE3.conf:1)
                 alias www.SITE3
         port 80 namevhost SITE1 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE1.conf:1)
                 alias www.SITE1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any Listen or Virtualhost declarations you might have in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.

Also, make sure that /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/SITE1.conf has the correct ServerName/ServerAlias.